# How to combine several models in the one DetailView

Tags: python, django

I have 3 models Course,CourseSection,SectionVideo and last 2 connected to the Course model. I want to create DetailView for the Course, which will contain all models, i mean where i can show sections inside and inside section show videos. How to do that?

```
class Course(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='courses/course_images',blank=True,null=True)
    cover = models.ImageField(upload_to='courses/course_covers',blank=True,null=True)
    tutor = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='tutor_courses',on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    students = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='course_students',blank=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(CourseCategories,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    certificate = models.ImageField(upload_to='courses/course_certificates',blank=True,null=True)
    languages = LanguageField(blank=True)
    rank_score = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
    price = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
    discount_price = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)

class CourseSections(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)

class SectionVideos(models.Model):
    video = models.FileField(upload_to='courses/course_videos',max_length=100)
    section = models.ForeignKey(CourseSections,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a DetailView for the top most entity (course in your example) https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/

and then override the get_context_data() and add the related information to the context and then in the template you can normally access it.

an example from the official documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#making-friendly-template-contexts

Comment: thanks, but how to filter exactly data that related to exact course, for example course's section, section's video?)

Comment: this would be:

CourseSections.objects.filter(section= section)

in the get_context as far as i remember you can access the section object with:

self.object  or you can look whats in the context of the super call and access it from there.

the videos you get the same way but for each course's section you do the lookup

Comment: can you explain me with code, because i tried what you said but nothing works

Comment: can you edit your question with the code you tried?